# What are the three gates at the left side of the Historia Crux?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

A [new user was wondering](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53827/3389)<sup>1</sup> about the three gates at the far left end of the Historia Crux. They apparently have no story significance and aren't unlocked normally.

What are they for?

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>: Was posted as an answer on a separate question, so it was deleted.

Comment: You asked and answered your own question within a minute?

Comment: @danRhul Yes: it's [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: Interesting. Never knew that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three gates appear to be related to DLC:

- The bottom gate leads to an alternate version of Serendipity and is unlocked if you purchased the *Sazh: Heads or Tails?* DLC.
- The middle gate leads to an alternate version of the Coliseum and is unlocked if you purchased or received any of the *Opponent* DLC: *Omega*, *Lightning & Amodar*, or *Nabaat*.
- The top gate cannot be accessed as of yet, but presumably it's for another, forthcoming DLC.

Comment: Knowing Square, I suspect the top gate is for Lightning's story.

Answer (score 0):

The top one is Lightning's DLC (episode), will come on May.

Answer (score -1):

far right is Valhalla for the lightning DLC and far right is sazh's dlc and another two that i believe is unreleased at this time